# What is the small graphic displayed under an EditText called and how can I remove it?

Tags: android, android-edittext

After some pretty thorough googling I still cannot figure out what the the little graphic that's displayed under the text in and EditText View is called. I would also like to remove it either using XML or programmatically. The little graphic is the thing under the cursor in this image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-UAuOq0h4Vok/T8reinvaWPI/AAAAAAAABPc/N4yibXd3kZg/s1600/android%2Bedittext%2Btext%2Bchange%2Blistener%2Bexample.jpg . Sorry if this is a dumb question, but without the name of this little graphic feature I can't seem to find out anything about it.

Comment: the graphic is the underline to show where the edit text is. why would you want to remove it, you wont be able to tell where the edittext is. it is part of the editext itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the background drawable associated with the edittext.  You can change it by manually setting the background to something yourself, such as

```
<EditText
   android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
   ...
   />
```

Comment: I was the one who told you the answer first..Atleast give my answer an upvote.. @sync

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<EditText  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:hint="@string/hello" 
      android:background="#00000000"
      />
```

if you want transparancy just put 80 before the actual hash code.

```
#80000000
```

This will change any colour you want to transparent one.. :)

Comment: I was the one who told you the answer first..Atleast give my answer an upvote.. @sync

Answer (score 0):

you probably have in your layout

```
android:minLines="2"
```

try to remove it